# D3 bar graph that changes data source on click of button, but mouseover tooltip on bars won't show before a button is pressed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```js
    var data1 = [
      { group: "A", value: 4 },
      { group: "B", value: 16 },
      { group: "C", value: 8 }
    ];

    var data2 = [
      { group: "A", value: 7 },
      { group: "B", value: 1 },
      { group: "C", value: 20 }
    ];

    var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60 },
      width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#viz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(data1.map(function (d) { return d.group; }))
      .padding(0.2);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 20])
      .range([height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "myYaxis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Initialize the bar chart with the first dataset
    update(data1)

    function update(data) {

      var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)

      u
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .merge(u)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.group); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")

      u
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          console.log('d', d)
          var tooltip_str = d.group + ': ' + d.value
          tooltip.html(tooltip_str)
            .style("visibility", "visible");
        })
        .on("mousemove", function (d) {
          tooltip.style("top", event.pageY - (tooltip.node().clientHeight + 5) + "px")
            .style("left", event.pageX - (tooltip.node().clientWidth / 2.0) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function (d) {
          tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
        })

      var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip");

    }
```

```css
    .tooltip {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #231F20;
      padding: 15px;
      opacity: .9;
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
      visibility: hidden;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: 1px solid #BCBDBC;
      font-style: italic;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="update(data1)">Variable 1</button>
  <button onclick="update(data2)">Variable 2</button>

  <div id="viz"></div>
```

I have a simple bar chart that updates the data source when clicking buttons.
The code is from https://d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/barplot_button_data_simple.html

I want to add tooltips to the bars. On load, they do not show up. But after clicking the 'variable 2' button, they do show. When you then click 'variable 1,' they show.

I can't fathom why they won't show up initially? I added a console log in the mouseover function, and it's not registering.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your snippet the variable `u` is storing the initial selection which is **empty** (the `.on` is then executed on this empty selection).   Simple fix is to update `u` to store the entering and merged rects.  See updated snippet:

```js
var data1 = [
      { group: "A", value: 4 },
      { group: "B", value: 16 },
      { group: "C", value: 8 }
    ];

    var data2 = [
      { group: "A", value: 7 },
      { group: "B", value: 1 },
      { group: "C", value: 20 }
    ];

    var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 70, left: 60 },
      width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#viz")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, width])
      .domain(data1.map(function (d) { return d.group; }))
      .padding(0.2);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, 20])
      .range([height, 0]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "myYaxis")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    // Initialize the bar chart with the first dataset
    update(data1)

    function update(data) {

      var u = svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(data);
        
     u = u
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .merge(u);
        
     u.transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d.group); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.value); })
        .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")

      u
        .on("mouseover", function (d) {
          console.log('d', d)
          var tooltip_str = d.group + ': ' + d.value
          tooltip.html(tooltip_str)
            .style("visibility", "visible");
        })
        .on("mousemove", function (d) {
          tooltip.style("top", event.pageY - (tooltip.node().clientHeight + 5) + "px")
            .style("left", event.pageX - (tooltip.node().clientWidth / 2.0) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function (d) {
          tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
        })

      var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip");

    }
```

```css
.tooltip {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #231F20;
      padding: 15px;
      opacity: .9;
      position: absolute;
      pointer-events: none;
      visibility: hidden;
      font-size: 16px;
      border: 1px solid #BCBDBC;
      font-style: italic;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="update(data1)">Variable 1</button>
  <button onclick="update(data2)">Variable 2</button>

  <div id="viz"></div>
```

Comment: I see. Thanks so much!